# Why is the database not created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use Entity Framework code-first.

DataBaseName - I want to create a database in SQL Server.

In `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;User Instance = False" />
```

in `global.asax`:

```
 protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
 {
     base.OnApplicationStarted();

     Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());
 }
```

`DataContextInitializer`:

```
namespace CodeFirstMembershipSharp
{
    public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus Status;
            Membership.CreateUser("Demo", "123456", null, null, null, true, out Status);
            Roles.CreateRole("Admin");
            Roles.AddUserToRole("Demo", "Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

`DataContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Auction)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuctionId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bid>()
           .HasRequired(a => a.User)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bid> Bids { get; set; }
}
```

But the database is not created. What did I forget to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Database.SetInitializer` *sets* the initializer but doesn't *run* the initialization. After `Database.SetInitializer` you need to add:

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

Comment: I get error One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

 System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'AuctionId' on entity 'Bid' does not match the type of property 'UserId' on entity 'User' in the referential constraint 'Bid_Auction'.

Comment: @simplydenis: The exception is a good sign because it proves that the database initialization is running :) The problem has nothing to do with your original question. Exception says that there is a type mismatch between key and foreign key properties but I can't say exactly without seeing the involved classes `User`, `Bid`, `Auction`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding the new data in your seed method, I guess you need to add them to datacontext so that entityframework will go create db and save the data, try something like below

```
namespace CodeFirstMembershipSharp
{
    public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            context.Users.Add(new User{name = "Demo", password = "123456"});
            context.Roles.Add(New Role("Admin"));
        }
    }
}
```